# Mapping function keys in insert mode

Tags: vim

I"m trying to map my compile and run commands to F5, It works fine in normal mode with the following:

```
nmap <F5> :<C-U>make<CR>:!%:r.exe<CR>:redraw<CR>
```

but when I try to do the same in insert mode:

```
imap <F5> :<C-U>make<CR>:!%:r.exe<CR>:redraw<CR>
```

It just prints out the characters F5 into my source code.

Is there a way I can have it work in both modes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
imap <F5> <Esc>:<C-U>make<CR>:!%:r.exe<CR>:redraw<CR>i
```

So it switches into normal mode and then back again.